# How to disable redactor tooltip entirely?

Tags: javascript, redactor

In redactor when I hover over toolbar buttons, tooltips fly over from left top to the place where toolbar button is placed. This odd behavior makes this tooltip pretty ugly and want to disable it.

[This link](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/How-do-I-remove-the-inline-editor-tooltip) describes disabling inline tooltip, but I'm looking for a way to disable the main tooltips.

How to disable it?

The black tool-bar in picture below has tool-tips, I want to disable tool-tips that appear on mouse over, as it has some buggy behavior.
[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you want to disable?

Comment: @JonasSchafft please the question.

Comment: Can you show a snapshot of the tool-tips when you mouseover it? My Redactor has no tool-tips

Comment: I could not produce it, as when I hover over it and take snapshot tooltips get hid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For removing tool-tips I did the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
         $('.redactor-toolbar-tooltip').remove();
}
```

It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can actually do it using just simple css

```
.redactor-toolbar-tooltip{
   display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not disable it with config or css. The only way I can see is to remove title attribute from anchors in toolbar.

```
Array.prototype.slice
    .call(document.getElementsByClassName('redactor-toolbar')[0].getElementsByTagName('a'), 0)
    .forEach(function(button) {
        button.removeAttribute('title');
    }
```

You can try to run above code after editor is created.

Comment: Thank you, I will test it and would tell the result. I hope it helps :)